# Getting 401 'Login Required' while accessing ga api url in browser

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

I am getting following exception in browser

```
   {  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"required",
            "message":"Login Required",
            "locationType":"header",
            "location":"Authorization"
         }
      ],
      "code":401,
      "message":"Login Required"
   }
}
```

using this [Google API Service](https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:XXX&start-date=2016-06-16&end-date=2016-06-19&metrics=ga:TimeOnPage) link.

I have obtain auth parameter from developer consol and send these parameter in request header of post request using RestClient and getting response code 404.

```
   {  
   "web":{  
      "client_id":"XXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "project_id":"XXX-1347",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"XXX",
      "javascript_origins":[  
         "http://localhost:8080"
      ]
   }
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to use these parameter to get timeOnpage metrics using above url.
Thanks

Comment: I think you should add apiKey parameter in your api call url

Comment: Hi @D.Dimitrioglo thanks for ur reply.While obtaining key there are two optioons  'server key' and 'brower key' ,so which one i need to create.

Comment: I work in php, but more detailes you can find out here - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

Comment: I have created key for browser and server both and passed one by one ang get same result.Can we get data using url in browser

Comment: @D.Dimitrioglo API key is for accessing public data only you cant access private google analytics data using a public api key.   He needs to authenticate to get access.

Comment: @DaImTo I mean OAuth key, not a public one

Comment: Ok however I am unsure what you would define as the auth key then for OAuth2 with Google Authentication  (Access token, refresh token, client id ?).   Please try  use the correct terms or you can cause problems for people new to Google Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics API requires OAuth2 or service account authentication in order to access private user Google Analytics data.

The "auth parameter" you say you are sending with is just the console application identification this will not give you access to a users data.  If you are trying to access another users data then you will need to use Oauth2 to request access.    Google has a tutorial on that [Hello Analytics API: Java quickstart for installed applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)

If this is your own personal data that you want to access possibly in order to share the data with others then you should check out service accounts. 
[Hello Analytics API: Java quickstart for service accounts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java)

**Anwser:** Your not authenticated so you cant access data.  That is why it says login is required.  And sending the json credentials you got from google developer console is not authenticating.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo for ur reponse. I have followed instruction given in quick guid and the given problem has been solved but i am getting different error    {
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}

Comment: check the service account you created in Google developers console that message means there is something wrong with the .p12 file.

Comment: I have created new .p12 file and trying to get data using V4 java api but still invalid grant error

Comment: You download the p12 file from Google Developers console when you create your credentials after first creating your application.  This is not a file you personally create.

Comment: reread section 1 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-java#clientId

Comment: Issue has been resolved after adding xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com account in my google analytics account under user management. I was incorrectly adding this account in console.developer page. Thanks for your help. Tutorial helps me to resolve the issue.